# Is there a Java library to convert a commandfile into parameters for main method

Tags: java, maven-2, command-line, maven-plugin, fork

I am working on a (Codehaus) Maven 2 Mojo. Unfortunately the logic called has a not compatible license and I have to fork a separate process (as it is done for Cobertura maven plugin).

Forking itself is easy using `org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline` and friends. The fork needs to be able to set thousands of arguments to the main method of the called process (which is the third party code to be used). On Windows, `Commandline` can only be 8k long. Using direct fork (`Runtime.getRuntime().exec`) supports only up to 32k total argument size, which is still not enough.

So I need a wrapper around the 3rd party tool, which reads lines from a text file (the command file) and calls the target class with them. **It's easy to code that and I could do it myself** but then I have another one of my classes calling the 3rd party code, which can't be in the Mojo's code base itself because of license problems (as above). Best would be a library that I can pull in as dependency that does that for me.

Do you know such a library/class I could use (without setting up another project, which needs to be released bla bla bla).

Comment: "The fork needs to be able to set thousands of argumends to the main method of the called process" Hahaha!

Comment: Obviously it wasn't designed to be used forked from a Mojo...

Comment: I have the weird sensation of being in a parallel universe. How can a "not compatible" license force you to spawn a process ? I mean, your plugin can use whatever license it wants, no ?

Comment: Plugin is Codehaus Mojo Apache licensed. Macker tool is GNU licensed. These licenses are incompatible (as I was told) and the only solution is to spawn a new process. I am no expert on license, I just try to commit a patch ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously (as no one answered) there is no such a thing to use out of the box. So I had to come up with one myself.

- To create the commandline file I copied `net.sourceforge.cobertura.util.CommandLineBuilder` ([source](http://cobertura.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cobertura/trunk/cobertura/src/net/sourceforge/cobertura/util/CommandLineBuilder.java)) which has `addArg()`, `saveArgs()` and `getCommandLineFile()` methods.
- To execute the commandline with that file I used `org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline` as commonly used in MOJOs.

  ```
  Commandline cl = new Commandline();
  cl.setExecutable( COMMAND_CLASS );
  cl.createArg().setValue( TASK_CLASS );

  CommandLineBuilder builder = new CommandLineBuilder( "macker" );
  for ( Iterator/*<String>*/it = options.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
     builder.addArg( (String) it.next() );
  }
  builder.saveArgs();
  String commandsFile =  builder.getCommandLineFile();
  cl.createArg().setValue( commandsFile );

  StringStreamConsumer stdout = new StringStreamConsumer();
  StringStreamConsumer stderr = new StringStreamConsumer();
  int exitCode = CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine( cl, stdout, stderr );
  ```
- The "other" side has to unpack the arguments. I wrote a small class `CommandLineFile` ([source](http://macker-maven-plugin.code-cop-code.googlecode.com/hg/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/macker/CommandLineFile.java)) for that.

  ```
  String className = args[0];
  Class clazz = Class.forName( className );
  Method main = clazz.getMethod( "main", new Class[] { String[].class } );

  List/*<String>*/lines = new ArrayList/*<String>*/();
  Reader in = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( args[1] ), "UTF-8" );
  try {
      lines = IOUtils.readLines( in );
  } finally {
      in.close();
  }

  main.invoke( null, new Object[] { lines.toArray( new String[lines.size()] ) } );
  ```
- The only problem that remained is the need for `CommandLineFile` to be on the classpath. But that is another story...

All used classes are generic and open source. So they could be used for any forking problem.

Comment: This source is now in the Apache SVN: http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/sandbox/macker-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/macker/